Net::OpenSSH not running the command?
I'm trying to get started using the Net::OpenSSH module and am running into issues.
I've tried a few different methods I've found online, but I dont seem to be able to get the output from a command on the remote device (nokia routers in this case).
I do see the login 'message' (warning about unauthorized access etc) when connecting but do not see any login prompts (should they be visible with Net::OpenSSH?).
I then see this message "Connection to  closed by remote host".
I cant tell what its doing since it isnt outputting anything else to the screen and it is not populating $fh.  Any ideas?
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ip = "";
my $username = "";
my $passwd = "";

            my $ssh = connect_to_device($ip);
            my $fh = $ssh->pipe_out('show card state') or die "unable to run command\n";
            while (<$fh>) {
                    print "$_";  
            }
            close $fh;
            undef $ssh;
    
    sub connect_to_device {
            my $deviceIpAddr = shift;
            $Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;  # Enable comprehensive debug output
            my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($deviceIpAddr,
                    user => $username,
                    password => $passwd,
                    timeout => 3,
                    strict_mode => 0,
                    master_opts => ['-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null']
            );
            $ssh->error and die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
            return $ssh;
    }

Debug Output:
# open_ex: ['ssh','-V']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 48 at offset 0
#> 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 48 5f 37 2e 34 70 31 2c 20 4f 70 65 6e 53 53 4c 20 31 2e 30 2e 32 6b 2d 66 69 | OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fi
#> 70 73 20 20 32 36 20 4a 61 6e 20 32 30 31 37 0a                                                 | ps  26 Jan 2017.
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 48
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(14149) => pid: 14149, rc: 0, err: 
# OpenSSH version is 7.4p1,
# ctl_path: /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, ctl_dir: /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/
# set_error(0 - 0)
# call args: ['ssh','-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null','-o','ServerAliveInterval=10','-o','ControlPersist=no','-2MNx','-o','NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1','-o','PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad','-l','<username>','<ipaddress>','--']
# master state jumping from _STATE_START to _STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# tracer attached, ssh pid: 14150, tracer pid: 14151
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
Warning: Permanently added '<ipaddress>' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
TiMOS-C-16.0.R11 cpm/hops64 Nokia 7450 ESS Copyright (c) 2000-2020 Nokia.
All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements.
Built on Wed Jan 29 11:57:40 PST 2020 by builder in /builds/c/160B/R11/panos/main
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_LOGIN
# passwd/passphrase requested (<username>@<ipaddress>'s password:)
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_AWAITING_MUX
# file object not yet found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad, state:_STATE_AWAITING_MUX
# file object found at /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad
# master state jumping from _STATE_AWAITING_MUX to _STATE_RUNNING
# call args: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad','-l','<username>@<ipaddress>','--']
# open_ex: ['ssh','-O','check','-T','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad','-l','<username>@<ipaddress>','--']
# io3 mloop, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 28 at offset 0
#> 4d 61 73 74 65 72 20 72 75 6e 6e 69 6e 67 20 28 70 69 64 3d 31 34 31 35 30 29 0d 0a             | Master running (pid=14150)..
# io3 fast, cin: 0, cout: 1, cerr: 0
# stdout, bytes read: 0 at offset 28
# leaving _io3()
# _waitpid(14161) => pid: 14161, rc: 0, err: 
# call args: ['ssh','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad','-l','<username>@<ipaddress>','--','show card state']
# pipe_out: 'ssh''-S''/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad''-l''<username>@<ipaddress>''--''show card state'
Connection to <ipaddress> closed by remote host.
# DESTROY(Net::OpenSSH=HASH(0xd7fd58), pid: 14150)
# sending exit control to master
# set_error(1 - control command failed: master SSH connection broken)
# master state jumping from _STATE_RUNNING to _STATE_KILLING
# killing master
# _master_kill: 14150
# waitpid(master: 14150) => pid: 0, rc: No such file or directory
# waitpid(master: 14150) => pid: 14150, rc: Interrupted system call
# master state jumping from _STATE_KILLING to _STATE_GONE
# master state jumping from _STATE_GONE to _STATE_GONE


In your sub, $username and $passw is not defined. Please show a complete minimal example. See [mcve] for more information

They are defined globally.

"should they be visible with Net::OpenSSH?" : I don't think you should see anything when Net::OpenSSH->new() is successful. Can you try enable debug output? Also, are you able to connect successfully from the shell using ssh user@ip_addr ?

I am able to connect via normal SSH (from the server i'm using or from my computer directly) and via other scripts that use Net::SSH:Expect. This new test is to try and get Net::OpenSSH working.
I believe this script is connecting, but something seems to not be working after that point.

"# call args: ['ssh','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/7d29d81a517f00787fb9ba9ca54353ad','-l','@','--','show card state']" What does "show card state" mean in that debug output?

'show card state' is the command to be run on the device.

To debug this, try enable debug output from Net::OpenSSH. For example:
use v5.38;
use Net::OpenSSH;

$Net::OpenSSH::debug = ~0;  # Enable comprehensive debug output
my $user = "hakonh";
my $host = "172.17.0.2";
my $port = 2222;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
    $host,
    user => $user,
    port => $port,
    passwd => '????'
);
$ssh->error and
  die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;

say "Successfully connected ";

# Shut down the connection by letting the `$ssh` object go out of scope

Please update your question with debug output like this. This can help us narrow down the problem.

I posted the debug output

@JasonM Thanks, also update the question with the exact script you used to produce the debug output.

Updated it with the additional debug line.

Thanks for the update. So it is this line that fails: my $fh = $ssh->pipe_out('show card state') or die "unable to run command\n"? Can you verify that?

It fails as in, it doesnt appear to actually populate that command, or possibly it doesnt run it.  It doesnt 'die' though, since its not printing that die message anywhere.
I verified in the device log that the login happened, but there's nothing indicating what happened with that command.

Instead of running like this: $ssh->pipe_out('show card state') try to give an array like this my $fh = $ssh->pipe_out('show', 'card', 'state')

I swapped in that line and the debug output appears identical.  Even the part where it shows the 'call args' and pipe_out line look the same.  And still no command output.

What happens if you run a standard command like "echo" instead? Example: my $pipe = $ssh->pipe_out('echo', '1', '2');

No difference, still no command output. I've tried quite a few commands of different types and all have the same issue.

And if you remove the $ssh->pipe_out() and the following 4 lines that uses $fh ? Do you still get errors?

I dont really get errors either way, just no command output.  If I leave those lines out, the only difference is it connects, then disconnects.

Ok, good so it is the output that is the issue then? When you run the ssh from shell you get output?

Yes, it works fine if I ssh directly to the device from the shell, or securecrt.  It also works fine if I use "net::ssh::expect" rather than net::openssh.

Let's check if it is the pipe() command that is the problem: If you run "ls" on the remote, do you get output? In the script you can try using the system() command: Example:  $ssh->system("ls") or   die "remote command failed: " . $ssh->error;

ls is not a valid command on the remote device, but I have tried 'system' before as well,
In the debug, the only difference is it is 'open_ex' instead of 'pipe_out'
open_ex: ['ssh','-S','/root/.libnet-openssh-perl/a3610065525649864c26673faadc75b5','-l','','','--','show card state']

Did you try with 'show', 'card', 'state' (3 args) and not 'show card state' (single arg) ? Example: my ($in, $out, $err, $pid) = $ssh->open_ex('show', 'card', 'state'); print "out = $out\n"

I did try that, it makes no difference.

Maybe try get more debug output from ssh itself by passing master_opts => ['-vvv'] to the Net::OpenSSH->new() call?

You could also try to determine if the problem is specific to the nokia routers ssh server by running it against other ssh servers

I dont have another non-nokia device to ssh to that would be reachable from here.  When I use "-vvv" I can see it authenticating, and I can see it trying to send the command I supply, but I dont get an error or any output.

Since Net::OpenSSH is just a wrapper for the ssh command, and ssh works from terminal. I would check that -vvv in the terminal also and check that you are passing exactly the same arguments as the -vvv shows in the perl script

As a test I tried telling the script to start 'interactive mode' by adding this line
$ssh->system;
It did login and land me at the command prompt of the device, though it did not attempt to run the command. That might require using 'expect' or something like it to interact that way.
This at least tells me that the login is actually working (confirming what I see in the logs), but something causes it to 'disconnect' if using any of the options to send a command (system, capture, capture2, pipe_out).  Not sure what is the deal with that.  It

See the section "Connecting to switches, routers, etc." in the FAQ: https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#FAQ  : ".... The best tool for this task is probably Expect, used alone or combined with Net::OpenSSH "

I'll look into possibly using openssh+expect. It may be the only option since it appears the more direct method wont work with these devices.  I appreciate your help on this.
